# Solr Dynamic Fields - add to "CopyField" without storing

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am using Mongo-Connector to index documents from MongoDB. As clearly known, mongo-connector flattens arrays so best method to index "arrays" is as follows:

dynamicField name="somefieldname*"  type="string"

field name="somefieldname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"

```
copyField source="somefieldname*" dest="somefieldname*"
```

I get the resultset properly in the field "somefieldname" and can use it to search but i am trying to avoid storing the dynamic values which come in as somefieldname.0, somefieldname.1

Is there a way to avoid this.

Comment: Have you tried `stored="false"` on the dynamicField? The `stored` property is `true` by default.

Comment: missed that. yes, that is the solution.